# Unexpected results reading a C# List of NameValueCollections

Tags: c#, list, indexing, namevaluecollection

I add three NameValueCollections to a List of NameValueCollections. When I read the NameValueCollections records back from the List and retrieve the values, I *expect* to see the three different values but instead each of the three returns the value of the third record ( the last record added ).
Please could someone de-confuse me? I seem unable to figure it out myself.
The (simplified) code below demonstrates my problem...

```cs
NameValueCollection record = new NameValueCollection();

List<NameValueCollection> records = new List<NameValueCollection>();

record.Clear();
record.Add("recId", "first record");
records.Add(record);
page += "<p>Added record: " + records[0]["recId"] + "</p>";

record.Clear();
record.Add("recId", "second record");
records.Add(record);
page += "<p>Added record: " + records[1]["recId"] + "</p>";

record.Clear();
record.Add("recId", "third record");
records.Add(record);
page += "<p>Added record: " + records[2]["recId"] + "</p>";


//-- OUTPUT ------------
foreach (NameValueCollection rec in records)
{
    page += "<p>rec.get(\"recId\") = " + rec.Get("recId") + "</p>";
}
```

Output:

```
Expected:
rec.get("recId") = first record
rec.get("recId") = second record
rec.get("recId") = third record*

Actual:
rec.get("recId") = third record
rec.get("recId") = third record
rec.get("recId") = third record
```

Comment: `record` has the same value. You need to re-inititalize record before adding to the list

Comment: `record = new Record()` instead of `record.Clear()`, you are always overwriting the current instance of record, and all three are set to the value of the last one loaded.

Comment: Thank you both so much! I appreciate the help.